# SUMO TraCI command not giving desired result

Tags: python, sumo

I am trying to get next traffic light that a vehicle will encounter during it's journey. For this we used `getNextTLS` from vehicle domain. The output does not show all the traffic lights on the way rather shows the same traffic light details repeatedly. Even when I run it for many simulation steps it doesn't print all (even though in GUI it clearly passes through them)

http://www.sumo.dlr.de/daily/pydoc/traci._vehicle.html#VehicleDomain-getNextTLS

```
while step < 1000:
traci.simulationStep()
#for id in t1.getIDList():
a=t1.getNextTLS(vehID= "202")
print("STEP:",step,"TLS:",a)

step += 1
traci.close(False)
```

Note: t1 is vehicledomain

Answer (score 0):

The following script works here:

```
import sys,os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ["SUMO_HOME"],"tools"))
import traci

traci.start(["sumo", "-c", "test.sumocfg"])
step = 0
while step < 1000:
    traci.simulationStep()
    a = traci.vehicle.getNextTLS(vehID= "1")
    print("STEP:",step,"TLS:",a)
    step += 1
traci.close(False)
```

I generated the network using

```
netgenerate --grid.alphanumerical-ids --grid --default-junction-type traffic_light
```

and used the following route file

```
<routes>
    <vehicle id="1" depart="0">
        <route edges="A2toB2 B2toC2 C2toD2 D2toE2"/>
    </vehicle>
</routes>
```

It would help to see the route of your vehicle.